# I need to calculate odd numbers of 3 column and display how many it has per column

Tags: c#, matrix

I need to do a matrix 6x3 and show how many odd numbers each column got. So this is what my theacher showed me to do ...

```
for (l = 0; l <= 5; l++)
    for (c = 0; c <= 2; c++)
        if (notes[l, c] % 2 != 0)
            cpt[c]++;
```

But I can't make sense out of it ... and how to use it after a lot of tries.

I am very so very confused...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Variable
    int[,] notes = new int[6, 3];
    int l, c;
    int cpt=0;
    Random hasard = new Random();
    // int number = hasard.Next(10, 26);

    // This enter the random numbers into the spreadsheet
    for (l = 0; l <= notes.GetUpperBound(0); l++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c <= notes.GetUpperBound(1); c++)
        {
            notes[l, c] = hasard.Next(10, 26);
        }   
    }

    //Display the spreadsheet
    for (l = 0; l <= notes.GetUpperBound(0); l++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c <= notes.GetUpperBound(1); c++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,3}   ", notes[l,c]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    // Here is where I would write how much odd numbers each colums got 
    Console.SetCursorPosition(3, 7);
    Console.WriteLine("colonne1   : ");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: If that's what he told you to do, you have good reason to be confused. He needs to read Code Complete and start using meaningful names for variables. Also, what the hammer is "notes" and "cpt"?

Comment: Also it in console apllication

Answer (score 0):

I guess all that was needed was to add

```
int[] cpt = new int[3];
for (l = 0; l <= 5; l++)
    for (c = 0; c <= 2; c++)
        if (notes[l, c] % 2 != 0)
            cpt[c]++;

Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
foreach (var icpt in cpt)
{
    Console.Write("{0,3}   ", icpt);
}
```

I agree the coding style is a bit weird, names of variables should be more descriptive and looping variables should be defined in the loop to minimize their scope, like:

```
for (int col = 0; col <= notes.GetUpperBound(1); col++)
```

Comment: Thx ! in which part of the code should I add this ?